# How to be notified when activity/task changes in Android

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I'm building a system status logger. I'd like to be notified when any activity/task is brought to the stop of the stack and becomes visible by the user (not just the one I wrote).

ActivityManager makes it possible to work out what's on top:
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html

however, this requires that I frequently poll to recalculate what's on top wasting a lot of resources. Is there a way to receive an event/callback/notification when an activity changes?

** edit ** To be clear -- I want to be notified when *any* activity becomes the active activity.

Comment: Did you ever get to solve this?

Comment: Polling was what we ended up doing. It turned out to be not-too-expensive.

Comment: Thanks Bro: http://i.imgur.com/Ie17FZ6.gif

Answer (score 0):

onResume() is called when activity comes to live state.

Comment: Sorry -- I should have been more clear in my question. I want to know of *any* Android activity has come to the top of the stack, not just one I wrote myself.

Comment: If something else come on top of your application your application/activity calls "onPause()" method. By that you can find something else has come to live state.

Comment: I don't really care about changes in the state of my activity. I want to know when onPause/onResume is called in *all other* activities.

Comment: what do you mean by "I want to know". I believe that is your app. So your app can know something else is running when the Android OS makes your app paused.

Comment: I would like my process to be notified when any process obtains or loses the foreground status (i.e. when any process becomes, or is no longer, the topmost activity).